# Game world rendering

Tags: 2d

I have a question about game world rendering. What is the best way to render background graphics such as grass and trees in 2D for your game?

Normally I would use array of tiles where every grass tile and tree are but I have big game world and for that this seems like too memory hungry solution

So what I need is nearly infinite game world rendering. the game I'm making is completely tileless and the game objects move using vectors

Also I need to render rivers

Some example pictures of what kind of game world I mean: [maps](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi.redd.it%2Fgjn27fbzusc21.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.reddit.com%2Fr%2FDnD%2Fcomments%2Fak2rfz%2Focart_map_of_the_greenfields%2F&tbnid=awc62hpsyBSCpM&vet=12ahUKEwiY4sG9ob7rAhXWB3cKHQ5DBZUQMygAegUIARCaAQ..i&docid=zJ01JPE3gdOIXM&w=1000&h=773&q=green%20fields%20map&ved=2ahUKEwiY4sG9ob7rAhXWB3cKHQ5DBZUQMygAegUIARCaAQ)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I store my 2D map in JAVA?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/162314/how-can-i-store-my-2d-map-in-java) (you didn't say what technology you are using, but the technique of using chunks should be available in anything which has a filesystem)

Comment: well that is about tile map which I plan to avoid using but the chunks is interesting approach

Comment: When you don't want to use a grid, then [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/141374/data-structure-for-logical-representatios-of-maps-for-a-2d-top-down-rpg/141424#141424) could also be interesting to you.

Comment: thx I was thinking of giving all the map objects (trees, rivers,hills) their own x,y coords if this is the best solution